# python, ThreadPoolExecutor, code doesnt finish

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have written a simple code like below. This is just a model of another, much more complicated problem. Here is a simple function "task submit" addint tasks in the queue, its aim is to continiously seek tasks deligated by used since user can create new tasks after the code has been launched. I have a worker, behaving like doing something, just a simple worker function. Then I call ThreadPoolExecutor, call "task submit" with queue argument. Then I start adding tasks pulled from queue. But it happens the code doest terminate even when only main thread (which is my program itself) remains in the pool of threads. Cant understand why even shutdown doesnt work.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Tpe
import time
import random
import queue
import threading


def task_submit(q):
    for i in range(7):
        threading.currentThread().setName('task_submit')
        new_task = random.randint(10, 20)
        q.put_nowait(new_task)
        print(f'                                {i} new task with argument {new_task} has been added to queue')
        time.sleep(5)


def worker(t):
    threading.currentThread().setName(f'worker {t}')
    print(f'{threading.currentThread().getName()} started')
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f'{threading.currentThread().getName()} FINISHED!')


with Tpe(max_workers=4) as executor:
    q = queue.Queue(maxsize=100)
    q_thread = executor.submit(task_submit, q)
    tasks = []
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print('\n\n------------NEW CYCLE----------------\n\n')
        if not q.empty():
            print(threading.enumerate())
            tasks.append(executor.submit(worker, q.get()))
        else:
            print('is queue empty?', q.empty())
            print(f'active threads: {threading.active_count()}')
            print(threading.enumerate())
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Comment: Just a quick glance at your code... you have `while True:` loop but no `break` anywhere...

Comment: Yeah but shutdown can terminate the loop, doesnt it?

Comment: cause the loop must terminate only after the last thread has finished

Comment: Re, "shutdown can terminate the loop." Why would you think that? You're calling `executor.shutdown(...)`. You're shutting down the _executor._ Why would you expect it to "shut down" anything else _but_ the executor?